# In iOS7.1, why is the itms-services protocal not available?

Tags: ios7

In iOS7.1, I want to install ipa by itms-services protocal, when i input "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://*.*.*.*/ipa_test.plist" into safari, it remind me "can't be connected to *.*.*.*".

But,In the same manner, I can install ipa normally in iOS 6.1.3 .

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is supossed to an iOS7 bug if anyone knows a solution, please share https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5385948?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7.1 (Beta) the plist url must be https